# Missing HLR-simulator in restcomm binary release

Tags: simulator, restcomm

I downloaded the binary release of Restcomm smsc from the link [1] mentioned in installation guide. When i unzipped it, I couldn't find hlr-simulator in it. It is supposed to be there as per the binary structure explained in the guide.

Should i build it separately?

[1] https://github.com/RestComm/smscgateway/releases/latest